# Can bash files have machine language?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I was installing [Anaconda Python](http://continuum.io/downloads#34) on Linux. For Linux, Anaconda provide a bash script, but the file is huge, almost 300 MB. I decided to see why, and opened it in a text editor.

About 95% of the file is machine language gibberish, like this:

```
ºîØôÐ•zÒA¶©h¶¥R•„&´ìÒUÓçß3{^eÑòà(|ÄÃkëŽ†ºîØôÐ•zÒA¶©h¶¥R•„&´ìÒUÓçß3{™½ö|q ŽÖm¶¥¡ôÚ­gú¡@óìÛkkº£C»Iš)à÷¾Û¸êw½æõîJN7í×p€A¡ÈzÞÝï8
```

The file isn't corrupt, as I can install Python.

Most of this is in the license file, so Im wondering if it's unicode for another language, but that wouldn't take 95% of the file, would it?

Can it be compiled code / machine language? Is it allowed to put machine code in bash files?

Comment: It's probably a self extracting binary. The actual script part will copy the gibberish part to a separate file(s), most likely doing some decompression along the way, then execute it. As long as the scrip exits before it reaches the non interpretable part, this is completely fine.

Comment: bash can handle embedded data in binary

Comment: For future reference, *machine language* or *machine code* is only one kind of *binary data*.  Your file definitely has binary data in it, but from what you've shown we don't know if it's machine code or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand on @Graeme's comment.

The downloaded script is a bash script with an embedded tarball. The *script part* first validates the tarball by md5sum, then unpack the tar, which contains multiple `.tar.bz2` archives. Then it proceeds by using a custom function `extract_dist()` to unpack the archives. I.e.:

```
extract_dist python-2.7.10-0
extract_dist conda-3.14.1-py27_0
...
```

which extracts the files:

```
python-2.7.10-0.tar.bz2
conda-3.14.1-py27_0.tar.bz2
...
```

For the 32-bit version the *script* part can be extracted by:

```
head -n 467 Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86.sh
```

For the 64-bit version the *script* part can be extracted by:

```
head -n 466 Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

As you can see the *script part* ends with `exit 0` which aborts any further processing of the script by bash.

The tarball is extracted by:

```
tail -n +469 $THIS_PATH | tar xf - --no-same-owner
tail -n +468 $THIS_PATH | tar xf - --no-same-owner
```

for 32-bit and 64-bit respectively.

You could for example do:

```
tail -n +469 Anaconda-2.3.0-Linux-x86.sh | tar -t
```

to list the files in the 32-bit archive.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason to do it this way, rather than just include a tar ball with the bash script, and extract it that way?

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari: For one, limit the n factors of faults that can happen between the keyboard and the chair. User downloads the 32-bit script and the 64-bit tar: Error. User downloads the 64-bit-script and the 32-bit tar: Error. User downloads old version of script and new tar: Error. Those are some of the most simple examples. Ease of distribution: distribute one file over e.g. torrent, FTP, HTTP or what ever. You could pack a compressed archive holding the install script and the tarball from where end user is expected to extract, read a README on "how to" etc. but ...